Updating RazorPayment Error, Success using UIViewrepresentable not working
I am implementing razorpayment in my SwiftUI app. I am using UIviewReprsentable to implement razorPayment. I have created struct RazorPayView: UIViewControllerRepresentable{..code..} to open the razorpayment page.
Issue is I am unable to send any data back from UIViewRepresentable to SwiftUI view. I am stuck here. I searched a lot tried all possible solutions with no success. I am able to go back to the SwiftUI view which is calling/opening the UIViewRepresentable but unable to receive any data. I also tried Binding var method didnt, it didnt work. I am trying to implement ViewModel now still same issue after cancel view is coming back with no data. Dont understnd what I am missing.
This is where I am calling UIViewRepresentable
struct PayCommon: View {
              /....code...../
                case "RazorPay":
                          payModel.getRazorOrderId{success in
                                if success{
                                        print("Successfully got both IDs")
                                }
                            }
                            default:
                                    print("Select payment method")
                                }
                        }
                }, label: {
                    Text("Button")
                }).background(
                        NavigationLink(destination: RazorPayView(payModel: payModel, razorKey: payModel.razorKeyId, orderId:payModel.razorOrderId),isActive:$payModel.openRazorPage,label: {EmptyView()}).isDetailLink(false))

In the above keyId orderId is successfuly sent to UIViewRepresentable and razorpayment page opens. Now,
protocol RazorViewControllerDelegate:AnyObject{
          func updateStatus(_ viewController:UIViewController,identifier: PaymentModel)
       }

      struct RazorPayView: UIViewControllerRepresentable{

      typealias UIViewControllerType = RazorViewController
      let razorKey: String
      let orderId: String
      @ObservedObject var payModel : PaymentModel

      class Coordinator:NSObject,RazorViewControllerDelegate{
        
        func updateStatus(_ viewController: UIViewController, identifier: PaymentModel) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                identifier.isCancelled = true
            }
        }
        var parent: RazorPayView
        
        init(parent: RazorPayView) {
            self.parent = parent
            }
       }
    
       func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
          Coordinator(parent: self)
       }
    
        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> RazorViewController {
        
        let controller =   RazorViewController(razorKey:razorKey,razorOrderId:orderId,sharedPayModel: payModel)
        controller.razorKey = self.razorKey
        controller.razorOrderId = self.orderId
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        controller.sharedPayModel = payModel
        return controller
        }
    
       func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: RazorViewController, context: Context) {
            }
        }

       class RazorViewController:  UIViewController{

        var sharedPayModel : PaymentModel
        var razorpay: RazorpayCheckout?
        var razorKey = ""
        var razorOrderId = ""
   
        weak var delegate: (RazorViewControllerDelegate)?
    
    
        init(razorpay: RazorpayCheckout? = nil, razorKey: String = "",razorOrderId:String =    "",sharedPayModel:PaymentModel){
        {
            self.sharedPayModel = sharedPayModel
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
            self.razorpay = razorpay
            self.razorKey = razorKey
            self.razorOrderId = razorOrderId
         }

        @objc func back(){
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
          }
        /...other code.../

}
          extension RazorViewController: RazorpayPaymentCompletionProtocolWithData {
    
          func onPaymentError(_ code: Int32, description str: String, andData response: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
            switch(code){
             case 0:
                let cancelAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Payment Cancelled", message: "\ (str)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) { _ in
                    self.back()
                }
                cancelAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
                self.present(cancelAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
               
        default:
            print("Carry On")
           }
         }

func back() is called successfully but i am getting nothing in published var of paymodel like isCancelled is set to true. How to call updateStatus() and  in extension and update paymodel var ??
